# DataTable is broken in Laravel & Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Can anyone help me? I am stuck in a strange kind of problem.
Why my Datatable is broken when I try to access it from the sidebar?

I've recorded a video to show you the live. Please watch the video.
https://www.loom.com/share/05636a61e9c1413a884bf8d19b1e420b

Your help will be much appreciatable 
Thanks in advance

```js
//File name - app.js

require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let Login = require('./components/auth/login').default;
let UsersListing = require('./components/users/index').default;
let Home = require('./components/home').default;
let Sales = require('./components/sales').default;

const routes = [
    { path: '/login', component: Login, name: 'Login' },

    { path: '/users-listing', component: UsersListing, name: 'UsersListing' },

    { path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home' },
    { path: '/sales', component: Sales, name: 'Sales' }
]


const router = new VueRouter({
    routes, // short for `routes: routes`
    mode: 'history'
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
//File name - index.vue(User Component)

<template>
    <div id="users-listing">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 layout-spacing">

            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h3>HTML5 Export</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="cancel-row">

                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12  layout-spacing">
                    <div class="widget-content widget-content-area br-6">
                        <div class="table-responsive mb-4 mt-4">
                            <table id="html5-extension" class="table table-hover non-hover" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Avatar</th>
                                    <th>Created at</th>
                                    <th>Updated at</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                                    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="d-flex">
                                            <div class="usr-img-frame mr-2 rounded-circle">
                                                <img alt="avatar" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="assets/img/boy.png">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ user.updated_at }}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" style="padding: 5px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-2 text-success"><path d="M17 3a2.828 2.828 0 1 1 4 4L7.5 20.5 2 22l1.5-5.5L17 3z"></path></svg></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete" style="padding: 5px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 text-danger"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">


    export default {

        created() {
            this.getAllData()
        },
        data()
        {
            return{
                users:''
            }
        },
        methods:{

            getAllData()
            {
                axios.get('/api/user/')
                .then(resp => this.users = resp.data)
                .catch()
            }

        }

    }



</script>

<style>

</style>
```

```html
//File name - Welcome.blade.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Mirrored from designreset.com/cork/ltr/demo1/index.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Sat, 13 Jun 2020 11:31:01 GMT -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>CORK Admin - Multipurpose Bootstrap Dashboard Template </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{asset('backend/assets/img/favicon.ico')}}"/>
    <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/loader.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/loader.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{asset('backend/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/plugins.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->

    <link href="{{asset('backend/plugins/notification/snackbar/snackbar.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/authentication/form-1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/forms/theme-checkbox-radio.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/forms/switches.css')}}">

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS/CUSTOM STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/datatables.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/custom_dt_html5.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/dt-global_style.css')}}">

    <link href="{{asset('backend/plugins/apex/apexcharts.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/dashboard/dash_1.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS/CUSTOM STYLES -->
    <link href="{{asset('backend/assets/css/main-custom.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="alt-menu sidebar-noneoverflow">
<!-- BEGIN LOADER -->
<div id="load_screen"> <div class="loader"> <div class="loader-content">
            <div class="spinner-grow align-self-center"></div>
        </div></div></div>
<!--  END LOADER -->
<div id="app">
<!--  BEGIN NAVBAR  -->

<!--  END NAVBAR  -->

<!--  BEGIN MAIN CONTAINER  -->
<div class="main-container sidebar-closed sbar-open" id="container">

    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="cs-overlay"></div>
    <div class="search-overlay"></div>

    <!--  BEGIN SIDEBAR  -->
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper sidebar-theme">

        <nav id="sidebar">

            <ul class="navbar-nav theme-brand flex-row  text-center">
                <li class="nav-item theme-logo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="{{asset('backend/assets/img/logo.svg')}}" class="navbar-logo" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item theme-text">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link"> CORK </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled menu-categories" id="accordionExample">



                <li class="menu active">
                    <router-link to="/home" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <div class="">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home"><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline></svg>
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </div>
                    </router-link>
                </li>

                <li class="menu menu-heading">
                    <div class="heading"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle></svg><span>USERS</span></div>
                </li>

                <li class="menu">
                    <router-link to="/users-listing" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <div class="">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-users"><path d="M17 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4"></circle><path d="M23 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-3-3.87"></path><path d="M16 3.13a4 4 0 0 1 0 7.75"></path></svg>
                            <span>Users Listing</span>
                        </div>
                    </router-link>
                </li>



            </ul>

        </nav>

    </div>
    <!--  END SIDEBAR  -->

    <!--  BEGIN CONTENT AREA  -->
    <div id="content" class="main-content">
        <div class="layout-px-spacing">

            <div class="row layout-top-spacing">
                <router-view></router-view>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  END CONTENT AREA  -->

</div>
<!-- END MAIN CONTAINER -->
</div>

<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/libs/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
    });
</script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->

<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/notification/snackbar/snackbar.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/components/notification/custom-snackbar.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/custom-notification.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/authentication/form-1.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/datatables.js')}}"></script>
<!-- NOTE TO Use Copy CSV Excel PDF Print Options You Must Include These Files  -->
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/button-ext/dataTables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/button-ext/jszip.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/button-ext/buttons.html5.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/table/datatable/button-ext/buttons.print.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    $('#html5-extension').DataTable( {
        dom: '<"row"<"col-md-12"<"row"<"col-md-6"B><"col-md-6"f> > ><"col-md-12"rt> <"col-md-12"<"row"<"col-md-5"i><"col-md-7"p>>> >',
        buttons: {
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn' },
                { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn' },
                { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn' },
                { extend: 'print', className: 'btn' }
            ]
        },
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": { "sPrevious": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-left"><line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg>', "sNext": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-right"><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline></svg>' },
            "sInfo": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
            "sSearch": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-search"><circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line></svg>',
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Results :  _MENU_",
        },
        "stripeClasses": [],
        "lengthMenu": [7, 10, 20, 50],
        "pageLength": 7
    } );
</script>

<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS/CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
{{--<script src="{{asset('backend/plugins/apex/apexcharts.min.js')}}"></script>--}}
{{--<script src="{{asset('backend/assets/js/dashboard/dash_1.js')}}"></script>--}}
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS/CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->

</body>

<!-- Mirrored from designreset.com/cork/ltr/demo1/index.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Sat, 13 Jun 2020 11:31:37 GMT -->
</html>
```

Comment: What does your web.php file look like?

Comment: @Savlon, here is how the web.php looks

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are loading jquery twice, with different versions.  I would suggest looking at the Developer tools for any errors relating to javascript.

Comment: There has only one jquery loaded v.3.1.1. And there has no error in the developer tools

Comment: What about bootstrap versions?  I think adminlte loads one by default.

Comment: Bootstrap v4.5.0 and this is a CORK admin template and I did mastering the template and loading components, so there is no possible way to load one by default.